# Disable Admin Approval Mode for Windows 10 Home Edition

Tags: windows-10

Hi anyone know how I can disable Admin Approval Mode for Windows 10 Home Edition?
It seems that Home Edition is missing some tools such as the local security policy editor. Do I have to hack the registry somewhere instead?

Comment: How about simply disabling UAC?

Comment: @gronostaj - One cannot fully disable UAC in Windows 10 ( or Windows 8.x ) due to a slight adjustment at least not without also disabling Universal Applications in the process.  Since many of the tools ( i.e. Calculator ) are Universal Applications this might not be the best idea.  I am still trying to determine what "Admin Approval Mode" is exactly.  *One can lower the UAC security level though which might achieve what the author wants.*

Comment: I've already disabled UAC / lowered the UAC level to the lowest setting. In Windows 7 Pro you could disable admin approval mode from the policy editor. So from my understanding it is how you avoid having to click the damn Run As Administrator on certain programs that requires elevated administrator permissions. Thus that effectively makes any administrator an elevated administrator by default.

Comment: @ColacX It seems that you have more understanding on differences between AAM and UAC than me and Ramhound. Can you please explain it to us? So far I understand that disabling UAC still requires you to request Administrator permissions, but they are granted automatically, without additional dialogs. Without AAM everything is started with Administrator permissions, just like in Windows XP. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is how it was in Windows 7 at least.

Answer (score 3):

Ah after some more googling I found the answer.

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-tweak-user-account-control-uac-options-in-windows-vista-home-basic-home-premium/

Open Regedit Set EnableLUA to 0

The guide is for Windows 7 but I have tested it works in Windows 10.0 Home

Comment: My copy of Windows somehow does not carry `secpol.msc`, and does not accept `net user administrator /active:yes`, so I'd given up hope when I found your answer. This is the only method that worked for me. You've just made my day, thanks!