# Deleting/Saving/Transferring files to and from C:/ always asks for Admin rights

Tags: windows, permissions, uac

To my understanding, I have admin rights set into my account. So when I move/copy/delete files to and from I am always getting a dialog asking for permission. There are no other user of this computer besides me.

How can I stop Windows 10 from telling me I need rights when I have set my account to administrator? I cannot do anything productive on my PC because it always annoys me with this security popups that warrants my attention.

This is costing me productivity.

Any thoughts on this?

EDIT

1. I've set UAC to never notify
2. I have software SDK's including the IDEs I use at work on C:\ which
   reside on an SSD. Imagine the horror of it asking permission on C:\
   again and again and again. I cannot even download source code
   without it ever asking permission.

Comment: download source code to what directory? what was the last version of windows you used prior to 10?

Comment: @Frank I am using a lot of directories though, some of it labeled SDKs. My Windows 10 just updated itself now. We can always assume latest as MS loves force updates. Also, I only used Windows 10, no prior version of Windows. I did not upgrade or anything.

Comment: Can’t you just work in directories that you have normal access to?  Or, if you must mess around in the root directory, just set the permissions on it to give yourself access.

Comment: Well my sdks is on C:\. In fact, my development workspace is on C:\. I will not put it on an HDD. Why? Its on an SSD. Building/opening projects are much faster on an SSD. IDE loads in seconds, builds the project I am working on in seconds. This is the reason why I bought an SSD. I also put the windows there so it boots in seconds. So I don't have to take coffee while I wait my pc to boot up.

Comment: If you're going to write to sensitive folders then this is what happens. There is zero difference between clicking OK in Windows and running sudo in Linux. This is easily resolved by following best practices. Don't write to the root of the hard drive, and change the permissions of the folders you are working with so that your user account has full control and not just "administrators." And don't write to other sensitive folders like c:\windows and c:\program files.

Comment: In order to avoid UAC prompts on protected directories you must disable UAC through the group policy by doing this though you will disable ALL UWP applications which include the Settings application.  You cannot fully disable UAC through any interface in Windows Settings

Comment: @FrankThomas By default `Authenticated Users` (which includes all currently logged on users) can create folders in the root of C:. Only admins can create *files* in the root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Answer: Grant Yourself NTFS Permissions to the Destination Folder

If you don't want to disable UAC (and face the consequences), you can easily dispense of the annoying *Are you sure?* prompts by granting yourself Full Control of the folder structure to which you are copying the files. It's a bad idea to do this to the root of your C: volume, so it would be prudent to create a folder in C: to which you have Full Control and then create all of your needed subfolders in there.

---

#### Long Answer: File Operations Trigger UAC Because (wait for it...) You're Not an Administrator!

OK...you *are* an admin...kinda. Read on to find out what this means.

You're getting prompted by UAC for file operations because your user account does not have at least NTFS write permissions to the destination folder. You're probably thinking, *"But I'm an Administrator! I have permissions to everything!"* If it was 2001 when Windows XP was released you'd be exactly correct. But starting with Vista and the advent of User Account Control (UAC), even members of the local Administrators group aren't treated like admins until after clicking *'Yes'* at a UAC elevation prompt.

When an Administrative user (specifically, a member of the local machine's Administrators group) logs on a modern version of Windows, the OS creates [*two* logon tokens](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574202(v=ws.11).aspx) (versions prior to Vista only generated one). One of the tokens keeps the administrative rights while the other is stripped of them--effectively demoting it to an unprivileged account. It is this latter token that you think of as your logon session because this is the token first presented for various operations as you go about your business in Windows.

With this information in mind, specifically that your non-privileged logon token is presented first, consider what happens when you access a folder. If you have rights to the folder (i.e. your Windows account name is listed in the ACL as granting permission to the folder), your *unprivileged* account has access, and **there's no UAC prompt.**

However, if your user isn't listed in the ACL, but the Administrators group is granted access *and* you're a member of the Administrators group, then Windows displays the UAC prompt.  If you answer 'Yes' to the prompt, **Windows retries the file operation using your 2nd logon token with Administrative privileges** at which point you gain access.

**Bottom line:** If you want to avoid UAC prompts for file operations, simply ensure your permissions to the destination folder are granted either directly to your user account, or to a group of which you're a member *other than* the local machine's Administrators group.

---

*Just to keep things interesting, the rules are different when you logon with the built-in Administrator account. Read more about that in my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1182227/213131).*

Comment: Is it ok to gain full rights over Program Files and Program Files (x86)?Some of the software I use like Android Studio, Genymotion, Virtual Box appears broken after install because upon running them they are all stuck or never open. I've search around and everyone says run it as admin and it worked.

Comment: @NeonWarge - Is it "ok", sure its "ok", but you shouldn't do it.  Most programs do not require Administrator permissions, and if a program is storing data in it's installation directory, then the program itself is poorly written.  If you want to be "break" the default permissions and run into any number of problems, feel free, to change the permissions on Program Files.  None of those programs required Administrator permissions, nor do they by default write any data, to Program Files.

Answer (score -2):

Disable or change the notification level of User Account Control (UAC) through system settings.

Keep in mind this will disable the administrative requirement notification for other things (such as running an app as admin) as well.

Edit: In regard to OP's edit, take ownership of the path you want to drag files to. So in your case, I think it's C:/SDK/

Comment: I just did. I'll edit my op to reflect this.

Comment: Edited my post @NeonWarge